Get Email (V2) in power automate is throwing an "ID is Malformed"
I am currently trying to get all email messages that are currently stored within our CRM system and move them to SharePoint instead.
I have a small temporary flow that I am fiddling with because of the error in the title.
In this small flow, I get a specific email and try to find it in Outlook:

And here is the error it returns:
  "error": {
    "message": "Id is malformed.",
    "code": "ErrorInvalidIdMalformed",
    "originalMessage": "Id is malformed."
  },


Any suggestions would be delightful!
Thanks in advance!
I have managed to get it to work by directly getting emails, so I have no idea why the CRM message ids are "malformed"?


I could be wrong but you’re combining connectors when I wouldn’t expect that to work.

What do you mean I'm combining connectors? From what I have read the messageID is set automatically when the email is tracked to CRM, are you suggesting that i may not have access to the email in outlook if it's in someone elses inbox?

Like I said, you were combining connectors, now that you're using the Outlook connector for both operations, it's no longer a problem.

I have figured out the solution.
So basically the Get Email (V2) by default attempts to retrieve it from the connectors inbox. So by specifying the "Original Mailbox Address" it is able to retrieve the outlook message (providing the connector has access to that mailbox).
This fixed it for me and is currently working.
